# Sails.js socket broadcast from shell script

Tags: socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

I have a Sails app and several Sails [Shell scripts](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/shell-scripts) run by cron or other external triggers (mostly me typing in the shell). I would like to implement notifications in the browser via builtin Sails socket client, which works but only when `sails.sockets.broadcast()` is called from a Sails Controller, that is, I was able to run the example from the [docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/realtime).

I can't succeed to broadcast a message from a shell script or even from `sails console --dontLift`, it seems that the registered clients are only on the socket that is running on the server and the shell/console instantiates another socket... makes sense but isn't possible to get those clients?
Is there any solution to broadcast a message from a Sails shell script to registered browser clients?

Furthermore, can I use Sails socket in a service worker to create push notifications? I understand that socket.io is different from Push, but is somehow feasible?

**update**

Thanks to @nahanil for pointing to redis, I found this article in the docs [Realtime communication in a multi-server (aka "clustered") environment](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/realtime/multi-server-environments)

Thanks!
Luca

Comment: Are you [using redis for handling socket.io stuff](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-sockets#?redis-configuration)? If not the shell scripts process won't be aware of clients connected to the 'actual' Sails app process. Could also be that the shell script is ending before the call to `broadcast` gets a chance to complete.

Comment: No, I'm not using redis for socket.io, yes that should be the problem! I'll check it out, thanks!